# How to make isResumed() return true for a Fragment in an ActivityUnitTestCase?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-testing

I've written a fragment class that, at a certain point, double checks [`isResumed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#isResumed()) before executing something. I'd like to write tests ensuring that this code runs. However, in my test cases derived from `ActivityUnitTestCase`, `isResumed()` always seems to return `false`. Is there some way to make it return `true` in such a test? I'm using the Support Library's fragment classes.

Here's an example test which uses similar code to what my real tests use, and demonstrates the problem. `testIsResumed()` always fails because `isResumed()` is false, despite having called `onStart()` and `onResume()` on both the activity and the fragment, and liberal usage of `waitForIdleSync()`:

```
public class FragmentIsResumedTest
        extends ActivityUnitTestCase<FragmentIsResumedTest.TestActivity> {
    public static class TestFragment
            extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return new LinearLayout(getContext());
        }
    }

    public static class TestActivity
            extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new LinearLayout(this));
        }
    }

    public FragmentIsResumedTest() {
        super(TestActivity.class);
    }

    public void testIsResumed() {
        startActivity(
                new Intent(
                        getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                        TestActivity.class),
                null, null);
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        TestActivity activity = getActivity();
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        fragment.onCreate(null);
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStart(activity);
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "FragmentTag")
                .commit();
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnResume(activity);
        fragment.onStart();
        fragment.onResume();
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

        assertTrue(fragment.isResumed());
    }
}
```

How can I make `isResumed()` true for my fragment in unit tests that extend from `ActivityUnitTestCase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's missing is that the test setup in the question never calls `Activity.onPostResume()`. In the Support Library's `FragmentActivity`, [this is where the fragments are resumed from](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/78096262864e71790fb0b7ca1566b945793287d1/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#444), by calling [`dispatchResume()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/78096262864e71790fb0b7ca1566b945793287d1/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#2053) on the `FragmentManager`. Simply calling `Fragment.onResume()` manually won't cause `isResumed()` to return true. And for some reason, `Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume()` [never calls `onPostResume()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Instrumentation.java#1255), and there's no corresponding `callActivityOnPostResume()`.

A simple fix is to make `onPostResume()` public in `TestActivity`:

```
public static class TestActivity
        extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

And call it sometime after `callActivityOnResume()` in the test setup. This appears to take care of all pending fragment transactions, so no more need for `executePendingTransactions()`. And the following test code works for me even after removing all calls to `waitForIdleSync()`. Using `Mockito.spy()`, we can see that all the lifecycle methods are called on the fragment:

```
TestActivity activity = getActivity();
TestFragment fragment = spy(new TestFragment());
getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStart(activity);
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "FragmentTag")
        .commit();
getInstrumentation().callActivityOnResume(activity);
activity.onPostResume();

assertTrue(fragment.isResumed());
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(fragment);
inOrder.verify(fragment).onCreate(any(Bundle.class));
inOrder.verify(fragment).onViewCreated(any(View.class), any(Bundle.class));
inOrder.verify(fragment).onActivityCreated(any(Bundle.class));
inOrder.verify(fragment).onStart();
inOrder.verify(fragment).onResume();
```